# How to bypass UsernamePasswordAuthentication in Spring Security

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm implementing an API that accepts a JWT as request parameter and on authentication, returns a new JWT.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate/token", method = RequestMethod.POST,
    consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity authenticate(@RequestParam("login_token") final String token, HttpServletResponse response) {
    LOG.debug("Request to login with token : {}", token);
    try {
        String jwt = authService.loginByToken(token);
        response.addHeader(JWTConfigurer.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, "Bearer " + jwt);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new IdentityToken(jwt));
    } catch (AuthenticationException ae) {
        LOG.trace("Authentication exception trace: {}", ae);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(Collections.singletonMap("AuthenticationException",
            ae.getLocalizedMessage()), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

My loginByToken implementation looks as below

```
@Override public String loginByToken(String token) {
    if (!tokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Token is invalid.");
    }
    SecureToken secureToken = tokenProvider.parseJwtToken(token);
    User user = userRepository.findByEmail(secureToken.getEmail());

    // TODO: Check Account Status is valid, User status is valid

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(new Date());
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, Constants.PASSWORD_EXPIRY_DAYS);

    if (user.getPasswordExpiryDt() != null
        && user.getPasswordExpiryDt().after(c.getTime())) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Password changed");
    }

    // TODO: Find how to create authentication object and return ID token.
    // return tokenProvider.createToken(authentication, false);
    return token;
}
```

At this point, I'm not sure how to create an authentication object that contains all user details that I could pass to `createToken` function that creates an identity token.

Here is my project without the changes mentioned in this post - https://github.com/santoshkt/ngx-pipes-test.

I have read about Anonymous Authentication, PreAuthenticated etc but not sure how to deal with this case. Will appreciate any pointers on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Spring Security, you should probably not use a Spring MVC endpoint to handle (pre-)authentication.

In your case you probably want to change your Spring security configuration so that it will have a filter that obtains your token from your request parameters and an authentication provider that retrieves the user/authentication object from your token:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .antMatcher("/authenticate/token")
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        // This is a filter bean you'll have to write
        .addFilterBefore(filter(), RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
        // This is your token verifier/decoder
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }
```

For the filter you could extend from `AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter` and make it return the `login_token` parameter. In here you have to implement two methods being `getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal()` and `getPreAuthenticatedCredentials()`.

```java
@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // You could already decode your token here to return your username
    return request.getParameter("login_token");
}

@Override
protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getParameter("login_token");
}
```

Your authentication provider should be of type `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider` and in here you can set an `AuthenticationUserDetailsService`:

```java
@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider provider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
    // service is a bean of type AuthenticationUserDetailsService
    // You could autowire this in your security configuration class
    provider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(service);
    return provider;
}
```

Now you can create your own `AuthenticationUserDetailsService` to retrieve a `UserDetails` object based on your token:

```java
@Service
public class TokenAuthenticationUserDetailsService implements AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserDetails(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken authentication) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // In this case the authentication.getCredentials() will contain your token and you can return a UserDetails object
       return new User(/** ... */);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to provide the HTML page for the JWT token request the best approach is that you create you own [Spring Security Custom Entry Point](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/AuthenticationEntryPoint.html)
You may give a look [here](http://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security) for an example

If it's another system to manage the authentication and you want just manage the authorization you can "trust" the other System and then manage your own authorizations; in this case you can use the `PreAuthentication Scenario` as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#preauth); you can find a sample [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-security/spring-3-security-siteminder-pre-authentication-example/)

I hope it's useful